# base b expansion of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory

This is a problem in Zygmund's analysis book. It is intuitively very straightforward. However, I could not give a rigorous proof. I hope someone can show me how to prove this rigorously.

**Problem:** There is an analogue for bases different from 10 of the usual decimal expansion of a number. If $b$ is an integer larger than $1$ and $0<x<1$, show that there exist integral coefficients $c_k$, $0≤c_k≤b$, such that $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_kb^{-k}$. Show that this expansion is unique unless $x=cb^{-k}$, in which case there are two expansions.

**Attempt:** I think Cantor's nested intersection theorem might be at play here. However, after constructed a collection of nested interval, I am confused on how to apply the theorem. Cantor's intersection theorem only suggests that the intersection of those nested interval is non-empty. How to I go ahead and conclude the intersection contains only one point? I know this seemed very messy...I hope someone could offer me a clean proof.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is essentially identical to the base $10$ expansion (which you seem to indicate you completely understand, otherwise you should not claim it is intuitively very straightforward). You just need to replace $10$ by $b$ (and remember that $9$ is actually $10-1$, so it should be replaced by $b-1$).

Answer (score 0):

(This is more a comment than an answer,
but it is too messy to enter
as a comment.)

After you have done the problem,
you can similarly show that
every real in
$(0, 1)$
has a unique representation
of the form
$x
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_k}{(k+1)!}
$
where
$0 \le c_k
\le k
$,
except for a countable set
that has two representations.

Generalizing further,
let $b_k$ be a set of
integers
with
$b_0 = 1$
and all other $b_k > 1$,
and let
$B_k
=\prod_{j=1}^k b_j
$.
Show that
every real in
$(0, 1)$
has a unique representation
of the form
$x
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_k}{B_k}
$
where
$0 \le c_k
\le b_k-1
$,
except for a countable set
that has two representations.