# Every positive real number has a base two expansion?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

"Every positive real number has a base two expansion." This is a statement from Folland Page $8$ and I wonder why it is true. Here is my procedure to express a given positive real number $a$:

Step 1: First we find the largest $n_1$ such that $a - 2^{n_1} \geq 0$ and $a - 2^{n_1+1} <0$. Let $a_1 = a - 2^{n_1}$

Step 2: Then we find the largest $n_2$ such that $a_1 - 2^{n_2} \geq 0$ and $a_1 - 2^{n_2+1} <0$

Repeat the step...

It is not hard to verify that $n_{i+1} < n_{i}$

Thus then $a = 2^{n_1} + 2^{n_2} + \cdots$

Define a $\mu$ function: $\mu: N \to \{0,1\}: \mu(x) = 1$ if $x=n_i$. $\mu(x) = 0$ otherwise

Thus then $a = \mu(2^{n_1})2^{n_1} + \mu(2^{n_1-1}) 2^{n_1-1} + \cdots$

Suppose $n_j$ is the first term that $n_j<0$.

Then we can express it even in 'decimal sense'

We write $a$ as $\mu(2^{n_1})\mu(2^{n_1-1})\cdots\mu(2^0).\mu(2^{-1})\cdots$

example: $32= 10000, 21.25 = 10000.01$

Can anyone give me some suggestions about my procedure? Intuitively I thought this statement is right. However, this statement is equivalent to $\mathbf{R^+}$ is embbed into $Q_2$

Comment: Do you know why every number has a decimal expansion?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yeah since $R$ is complete?

Comment: Are you saying that this implies the reals embed into the rationals? No, because any rational will have some pattern in its binary expansion, so it can be described as some finite initial string followed by some additional finite string which repeats forever. But an irrational can have an irregular binary expansion.

Comment: The base two expansion is not guaranteed to terminate after any finite number of terms. It _might_ terminate (as it does in your two examples), but "almost all" of the real numbers have non-terminating base-two expansions.

Comment: @Ian. Maybe not rational, but the completion of $Q$ in $2$ sense. (2-adic field?)

Comment: @DavidK Yeah I do not expect it to terminate. What I want to show is that given any positive real number, I could always express it only involving $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Nope, this isn't how you construct the 2-adic numbers. This really does get you the (nonnegative) reals.

Comment: Yes, you can express any positive real number using only $0$ and $1$. There are uncountably many ways to string together a non-terminating sequence of $0$ and $1$, so there are enough representations. Some numbers will even have two representations. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253374/base-b-expansion-of-real-numbers?rq=1

Comment: Just to confirm the comment of @Ian, I can assure you that the binary expansion of real numbers has nothing to do with $2$-adic numbers.

Comment: Would "yeah since $\Bbb R$ is complete" count as an answer for you as to why every real number has a binary expansion?